# Project to have an API to get a list of prices and name along with python

Tags: python, api

I am novice to the API field and want to learn the basics of API. I am also learning python. Can I use python along with API to achieve the goal provided below?

My ULTIMATE goal is to identify the price of a product from all the Big retailers and compare the price list.

Also kindly advise what are the tools, programing language that I need to have/learn apart from python and API.

```
[
    {
        name: xxx,
        id: xxx,
        price: xxx,
        Shop Name: xxx
    },
    {
        name: xxx,
        id: xxx,
        price: xxx,
        Shop Name: xxx 
    },
]
```

Comment: Add format of input and output which you want

Comment: Your question is too vague and broad for this site unfortunately, but I wish you best of luck on your journey! Break the problem down into smaller pieces, e.g. pick just one retail website and work out how to fetch details of one product and extract the price - this is still quite a big task, especially as a beginner. Here is a tutorial which may help to start you in the right direction https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 major steps with 2 main 'programs'

## step 1

create a basic server

the two good frameworks I have experience in python are [Django](https://pypi.org/project/Django/) and [Flask](https://pypi.org/project/Flask/). Another that I don't have experience in but have heard good things about is [fastAPI](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/)

Going through a tutorial for any to get a basic 'hello world' API endpoint running would be a good first step.

#### note

For this purpose, it won't make much of a difference if your api is REST, SOAP, or RPC. If none of these mean anything to you right now, that's ok. You'll learn more as you follow tutorials.

## step 2

Create a webscraper to get prices for a product from a company site

Realistically, you'll probably want to create a list of all the companies / sites you'll want to include in your search for best prices.

It'll be best to try and get your webscraper functioning for a single site, and then expand it to each other site.

two decent tutorials for doing this are [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/scraping-multiple-amazon-stores-with-python-5eab811453a8)
and [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/scraping-amazon-product-information-using-beautiful-soup/)

After you're able to run your script and get best prices from a single site, expand it to be able to scrape all the sites in your list.

Each site will likely need it's own method, as the site layout and keywords to search for in the html/xml will be different per site.

Once you're able to run your script by giving it some product name and you get the best prices from an assortment of sellers, you're ready for step 3

## step 3

put it all together

once you have a basic api endpoint, and your script to get best prices from sellers, all you need to do is format your script as a module in django or flask, then import and call the methods in your api endpoint.

In order to optimize (there are probably going to be a ton of sites in the list eventually), you'll want to look into threading and asynchronous tasks. Django is better for multithreading than flask if this is something you think you'll definitely want to implement

## notes

the 2 major components of this are and api endpoint to serve your information, and a webscraper to gather the information.

Either of these pieces can be done in most programming languages

Python is a fine language for this, but I would personally recommend TypeScript and nextjs or a nodejs based framework for the api endpoint.
Another great option is Go, as Go inherently has amazing support for threading via [Channels](https://go.dev/tour/concurrency/2) that would make calling python scripts at the same time and waiting for all to finish a fairly simple task

Python is still a great use case for webscraping, so if you go with a nodejs or Go based server, you'll want to have each site's webscraping in separate scripts, so that distinct programs can be called to run concurrently.

## recap

you need a server and a webscraper. any language and framework is acceptable for either.